# I want to use the latest version of ubuntu

Tags: 12.04

How can I install the latest version of ubuntu in my laptop without harming my windows 8.1?
My laptop is just two months old and I am all set to receive windows10 and I want to use both.. so help me

Comment: possible duplicate of [Installing Ubuntu on a Pre-Installed Windows 8 (64-bit) System (UEFI Supported)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported)

Answer (score 0):

The best way would be definetly to use [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/) without harming your Host OS,although it brings performance problem,DualBoot(Booting on OS selection) would also do the work

Comment: ohk thnks a lot

Comment: if it solved your problem or it was what you were looking for,you accept the answer or upvote

Comment: but it didn't :(